# Accessing values in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I have a JSON object `event.body` which contains `{"article_url": "http://technewstt.com/bd1108/"}` how can I access the value for `article_url` in other words I want to use the string `http://technewstt.com/bd1108/`. 
 I tried `event.body.article_url` and `event.article_url` and they both are `undefined`

Comment: Are you sure `event.body` do contains the value that way? Because `event.body.article_url` should work.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT yes I am sure because I did a `console.log` on `event.body` and it shows that the content `{"article_url": "http://technewstt.com/bd1108/"}` within it

Comment: What about `console.log(typeof event.body)` and `console.log(Object.keys(event.body))`

Comment: `console.log(typeof event.body)` returns `string` and `console.log(Object.keys(event.body))` returns the numbers 0 to 47

Comment: So try `JSON.parse(event.body).article_url`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT `JSON.parse(event.body).article_url` works thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure `event.body` contains the correct data, you can parse it with json and get the *value* and *key*

```
JSON.parse('{"article_url": "http://technewstt.com/bd1108/"}', (key, value) => {
  console.log(key);  //logs the key which is article_url
  return value;      // returns the url value
})
```

which is equivelant to

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.body), (key, value) => {
  console.log(key);  
  return value;      
})
```

Other option, like the user @Grégory NEUT commented will return the url value

```
JSON.parse(event.body).article_url  //returns the url value
```

Comment: The value that I need is returned thanks also going to try `JSON.parse(event.body).article_url`

Answer (score 0):

Best way:

```
var url = JSON.parse(event.body).article_url;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then, you should be fine.

Comment: This is indirectly a valid suggestion in case that OP uses the connect package.